# How can one name a type family as a higher-order kind function

Tags: haskell, ghc

Is it possible to use a type family as a higher-order "type function" to pass to another type family? A simple example would be the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
module Test where
import GHC.TypeLits as T

type family Apply (f :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat) (n :: Nat) (m :: Nat) :: Nat where
  Apply f n m = f n m

type family Plus (n :: Nat) (m :: Nat) :: Nat where
  Plus n m = n T.+ m

type family Plus' (n :: Nat) (m :: Nat) :: Nat where
  Plus' n m = Apply (T.+) n m
```

The first declaration of `Plus` is valid, while the second one (`Plus'`) produces the following error:

```
Test.hs:19:3: error:
    • The type family ‘+’ should have 2 arguments, but has been given none
    • In the equations for closed type family ‘Plus'’
      In the type family declaration for ‘Plus'’
   |
19 |   Plus' n m = Apply (T.+) n m
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Is there a way to use the `Apply` type function to implement `Plus`?

**EDIT** A commenter linked to the feature request report at https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9898. It mentions the `singleton` library. I would be happy with an example of using it or other "workarounds" to achieve a similiar effect of abstracting over the arithmetic operations on `Nat` such as `+`, `*`, `-` and `Mod`.

Comment: No, I 'm afraid that's no possible. [See this report](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9898).

Comment: Being able to partially apply type synonyms or type families would effectively allow type-level lambdas, which Haskell very intentionally does not support. (It makes type inference extraordinarily difficult, and Haskell tries to have good type inference.)

Comment: FTR, the problem is not that you can't have a higher-order type function, just you can't pass `(T.+)` as an argument because it is defined as a type family. This wouldn't be a problem though for e.g. a plain parametric data type.

Comment: @JorgeAdriano Thank you for the resources regarding this. I would be happy with a workaround, please see my edit. My primary goal is to copy & paste multiple similiar definitions that use T.+, T.-, T.* and T.Mod

Comment: See "defunctionalization" for a workaround technique

Comment: besides `singletons`, another way of doing defunctionalization is `first-class-families`, see http://blog.poisson.chat/posts/2018-08-06-one-type-family.html (I'm the author).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A useful approach is defunctionalization. You can implement it yourself, or find an implementation in the `singletons` library.

The core is an “open kind”:

```
data TYFUN :: Type -> Type -> Type
type TyFun a b = TYFUN a b -> Type
```

`TyFun a b` is an open kind; it is not closed like a normal, promoted, `data` kind. You “declare” new functions as follows.

```
data Plus :: TyFun Nat (TyFun Nat Nat)
```

You can then define this type family to link declaration and definition

```
type family Apply (f :: TyFun a b) (x :: a) :: b
data PlusSym1 :: Nat -> TyFun Nat Nat -- see how we curry
type instance Apply Plus x = PlusSym1 x
type instance Apply (PlusSym1 x) y = x + y
```

Now, `Plus` is a normal type constructor: a data type, not a type family. This means you are allowed to pass it to other type families. Note that they must be `TyFun` aware themselves.

```
type family Foldr (cons :: TyFun a (TyFun b b)) (nil :: b) (xs :: [a]) :: b where
    Foldr _ n '[] = n
    Foldr c n (x:xs) = Apply (Apply c x) (Foldr c n xs)
type Example = Foldr Plus 0 [1,2,3]
```

The idea behind the open kind is that `Type` is already an open kind, and kinds like `A -> Type`, `A -> B -> Type` are themselves open. `TYFUN` is a tag to identify things as  `TyFun`s, and `TyFun` is an open kind that is effectively disjoint from other open kinds. You can also use the `Type` open kind straight:

```
type family TyFunI :: Type -> Type
type family TyFunO :: Type -> Type
type family Apply (f :: Type) (x :: TyFunI f) :: TyFunO f
data Plus :: Type
data PlusSym1 :: Nat -> Type
type instance TyFunI Plus = Nat
type instance TyFunO Plus = Type
type instance TyFunI (PlusSym1 _) = Nat
type instance TyFunO (PlusSym1 _) = Nat
type instance Apply Plus x = PlusSym1 x
type instance Apply (PlusSym1 x) y = x + y
```

On the plus side, this can handle dependent type functions, but, on the other hand, it only does that because it shamelessly throws out kind checking by making everything “`Type`ly-typed”. This is not as bad is `String`ly-typed code, as it’s all compile-time, but still.